# How to call document.execCommand('copy') without clicking?

Tags: javascript

I have a site on http where after publishing a post, I need to copy the url of this post to the clipboard.

I made the observer

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, mutationInstance) {
  const link = document.querySelector('#message > p > a')
  if (link) {
    unsecuredCopyToClipboard(link.href)
    mutationInstance.disconnect()
  }
})

observer.observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
})
```

and that function

```
function unsecuredCopyToClipboard(text) {
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea')
  textArea.value = text
  document.body.appendChild(textArea)
  textArea.focus()
  textArea.select()
  console.log(window.getSelection().toString())
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy')
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful'
    console.log('Fallback: Copying text command was ' + msg)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to copy to clipboard', err)
  }
  document.body.removeChild(textArea)
}
```

I see in the console correct selection (the link I need) and a message:
Fallback: Copying text command was unsuccessful

I think it's because all document.execCommand('copy') calls must take place as a direct result of a user action, e.g. click event handler - [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

So, is there any way to get the link I need in the clipboard without clicking?

Comment: No. As you said yourself "*all document.execCommand('copy') calls must take place as a direct result of a user action*"

Comment: It is ***impossible*** to do this without a user event. For safety reasons, the web browser will not run the command unless it was executed due to an event from the user, such as a button press. In conclusion, the answer is: No, you cannot do this without clicking.

Answer (score -1):

using document.execCommand('copy') in input tow error:
1.input not have disabled class type
2.input not have hidden and display

so?fix just add a input it set class style for opacity:0; and then hide select this input copy text.

Comment: Still, the copy won't be executed unless is the direct result of some user interaction (eg a click ...)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).